# C++Builder маленькая проблема

Tags: c++builder

как в C++Builder  создать в баттоне, выражение которое вычисляет по формуле Герона площадь, то есть именно код, пробовал

```
  void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
    {
    int storona1, storona2, storona3;
    float plowad,p;
    storona1=StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
    storona2=StrToInt(Edit2->Text);
    storona3=StrToInt(Edit4->Text);
    p=(storona1+storona2+storona3)/2.0;
    plowad=sqrt(p*(p-storona1)*(p-storona2)*(p-storona3));
    Edit3->Text=FloatToStr(plowad);
    }
```

Comment: 1. научитесь объявлять переменные правильно
2. 2.0 и 2 - литералы разных типов. Деление int на int дает как ни странно именно int. Вам нужно вещественное число
3. если хотите изучить С++, то смените IDE и компилятор на что-нибудь более нормальное, иначе так и будете программировать мышкой по форме с кнопками
4. Старайтесь давать переменным осмысленные англйские названия. Впрочем, это всего лишь пожелание

Comment: я бы с удовольствием, только  заставили делать именно на нем

Comment: в институте что ли?

Comment: в университете

Comment: значит с преподом вам не повезло (или даже с универом) Borland C++ (и его потомки) - весьма сомнительный выбор для изучения С/С++

Впрочем, это все неважно. Вам ,надеюсь, понятно, что не так с вашим кодом?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_pushbutton

В обработчике нажатия на кнопку не надо помещать всю логику программы.

Comment: если честно то не особо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

хорошо, по порядку.

а) у вас ошибка в строке

```
plowad=float sqrt(p*(p-storona1)*(p-storona2)*(p-storona3));
```

ошибка в том, что слово float тут лишнее.

б) переменная объявлена как powad, а вы пишете plowad, это видимо просто опечатка

в) следующая ошибка в строке

```
p=(storona1+storona2+storona3)/2
```

дело в том, что и числитель и знаменатель у вас имеют тип int. А когда вы делите int на int то в ответе получаете тоже целое число даже если должен быть остаток. Например: 5/2 с точки зрения математики равно 2.5 а с точки зрения Си равно  двум. Поэтому чтобы получить корректный результат, вам надо написать вот так:

```
p = (storona1 + storona2 + storona3) / 2.0 // 2.0 - это уже число с плавающей точкой, поэтому в результате вы получите тоже число с плавающей точкой
```

либо так:

```
p = (float)(storona1 + storona2 + storona3) / 2
```

г)  Не ошибка, а просто пожелание на будущее. Не пишите переменные транслитом. Это очень дурная практика. Лучше называйте английскими словами, заодно знание языка подтянете, лишним не будет. И еще соглашусь с [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd) - не надо запихивать все расчеты в Button1Click. Впрочем, чем это плохо, вы сможете понять, прочитав приведенную ссылку из Википедии. Однако если ваш препод не совсем дурень, то увидев, что вы вынесли логику из обработчика кнопки в отдельные классы и/или функции, он должен это оценить

Comment: какая то ошибка   plowad=sqrt(p*(p-storona1)*(p-storona2)*(p-storona3))

Comment: plowad=float sqrt(p* (p-storona1)* (p-storona2)*(p-storona3))

Comment: plowad=sqrt(p*(p-storona1)*(p-storona2)*(p-storona3))

Comment: вы знак * пропустили  между двумя скобками

Comment: я поставил так , но все равно что то не то, подключил библиотеку cmath.h

Comment: ничего не понял. Приведите лучше код, который у вас сейчас

Comment: вы в двух местах пропустили знак *. В отличие от математики в языках программировния это не допускается.  Должно быть так: 

    plowad = sqrt(p*(p - storona1)*(p - storona2)*(p-storona3));

Comment: еще после 2.0 точку с запятой поставьте